# How to only pass values where there are x amount of consecutive not-null values in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a time series of monthly temperature anomaly data that is 60 years long. I would like to only pass temperature values where there are 6 or more consecutive months in the time series where temperature anomalies are greater than 0.5. Although I find it easy enough to replace the values < 0.5 with NaN, I'm not sure how to replace values where the temperature is > 0.5 but there are only 2 or 3 consecutive values that are greater than 0.5. Snippet below:

```
time = [1950.04167, 1950.125  , 1950.20833, 1950.29167, 1950.375  ,
       1950.45833, 1950.54167, 1950.625  , 1950.70833, 1950.79167,
       1950.875  , 1950.95833, 1951.04167, 1951.125  , 1951.20833,
       1951.29167, 1951.375  , 1951.45833, 1951.54167, 1951.625  ,
       1951.70833, 1951.79167, 1951.875  , 1951.95833, 1952.04167,
       1952.125  , 1952.20833, 1952.29167, 1952.375  , 1952.45833,
       1952.54167, 1952.625  , 1952.70833, 1952.79167, 1952.875  ,
       1952.95833, 1953.04167, 1953.125  , 1953.20833, 1953.29167,
       1953.375  , 1953.45833, 1953.54167, 1953.625  , 1953.70833,
       1953.79167, 1953.875  , 1953.95833, 1954.04167, 1954.125  ,
       1954.20833, 1954.29167, 1954.375  , 1954.45833, 1954.54167,
       1954.625  , 1954.70833, 1954.79167, 1954.875  , 1954.95833]


sst = [-1.67623 , -1.685853, -1.69083 , -1.61898 , -1.40235 ,
       -1.097773, -0.835867, -0.718727, -0.694087, -0.785423,
       -0.9312  , -1.01925 , -0.8868  , -0.48022 , -0.007597,
        0.448647,  0.66546 ,  0.852427, 0.922443,  1.14481 ,
        1.291153,  1.338903,  0.993053,  0.68006, 0.493597,
        0.500197,  0.528363,  0.515583,  0.418493,  0.168387,
       -0.003403,  0.033933,  0.15759 ,  0.113847,  0.019967,
        0.111413, 0.372967,  0.623067,  0.763903,  0.909743,
        0.990287,  1.01288 , 0.969407,  0.985817,  0.982607,
        1.01244 ,  1.039917,  1.11755, 1.044333,  0.799593,
        0.3769  ,  0.105033, -0.070743, -0.281483, -0.59861,
        -0.875743, -0.88768 , -0.642517, -0.548043, -0.547057]


series = pd.Series(index=time,data=sst)
greater = series.where(cond=(series>= 0.5))
```

So for example, I'd like to be able to 'pass' the SST values that correspond to the time spans of 1951.375 to 1951.95833 and 1953.125 to 1954.125 where SST is greater than 0.5 for 8 and 13 consecutive values respectively, but replace the SST values with NaN for the SST values corresponding to 1952.125 to 1952.29167 where there are only 3 consecutive values that are > 0.5.

Any suggestions? TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the length of `> 0.5` runs with `series.groupby(series.le(0.5).cumsum())` and then use `.apply()` to replace values with runs that are too short.

The `.groupby` ends up lumping the last `<= 0.5` value, and so we want to limit it to runs of 5 of more and to replace the first value with an `np.nan`.

```
In [61]: (
    series
    .groupby(series.le(0.5).cumsum())
    .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.nan if len(x) < 5 else [np.nan] + list(x)[1:], x.index))
)
Out[61]:
1950.04167         NaN
1950.12500         NaN
1950.20833         NaN
1950.29167         NaN
1950.37500         NaN
1950.45833         NaN
1950.54167         NaN
1950.62500         NaN
1950.70833         NaN
1950.79167         NaN
1950.87500         NaN
1950.95833         NaN
1951.04167         NaN
1951.12500         NaN
1951.20833         NaN
1951.29167         NaN
1951.37500    0.665460
1951.45833    0.852427
1951.54167    0.922443
1951.62500    1.144810
1951.70833    1.291153
1951.79167    1.338903
1951.87500    0.993053
1951.95833    0.680060
1952.04167         NaN
1952.12500         NaN
1952.20833         NaN
1952.29167         NaN
1952.37500         NaN
1952.45833         NaN
1952.54167         NaN
1952.62500         NaN
1952.70833         NaN
1952.79167         NaN
1952.87500         NaN
1952.95833         NaN
1953.04167         NaN
1953.12500    0.623067
1953.20833    0.763903
1953.29167    0.909743
1953.37500    0.990287
1953.45833    1.012880
1953.54167    0.969407
1953.62500    0.985817
1953.70833    0.982607
1953.79167    1.012440
1953.87500    1.039917
1953.95833    1.117550
1954.04167    1.044333
1954.12500    0.799593
1954.20833         NaN
1954.29167         NaN
1954.37500         NaN
1954.45833         NaN
1954.54167         NaN
1954.62500         NaN
1954.70833         NaN
1954.79167         NaN
1954.87500         NaN
1954.95833         NaN
dtype: float64
```